# CSS3: Transforming ONLY during Transition

Tags: css, scale, transition, transformation

I know we can transform shape (e.g. circle to square) from one state (e.g. top: 0) to another state (e.g. top: 20px). But I'm not sure how we can keep the shape at both states intact (i.e. keeps it circled @ top: 0 and top: 20px), but ONLY during transition I want to transform its shape. An example of what I want to achieve is somewhat like this:

[image]

Comment: Add a class when the transition starts, then watch for transition end using the `transitionend` event and remove the class.

Comment: well, I never thought of it before. BTW cannot it be done without using javascript?

Comment: I'm thinking about your suggestion, but i'm not sure how to detect when the transition has started? I can only see `transitionend ` event.

Comment: Keyframes would be how I would do it. Have you looked into those?

Comment: You know when the transition has started because you are the one starting it, most likely by placing some class on some element.

Comment: @torazaburo Yeah, understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pure css version of what you want. It transforms only during the transition. Not hard at all. Just use keyframes to specify what properties you want changed and when.

The HTML

```
  <div class="childAnimated"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
```

And the CSS

```
.child {
  border: .5em solid white;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.childAnimated {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: white;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 5em;
  -webkit-animation: gooAnim 4s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes gooAnim {
  0%   { top: 1em; }
  25%   { top: 3.8em; left: 1.5em; width: 2em; height: 2em; }
  50%  { top: 6em; width: 3em; height: 3em; left: 1em;}
   75%   { top: 8.8em; left: 1.5em; width: 2em; height: 2em; }
  100% { top: 11em; }
}
```

If you want to see it in action, here's the codepen. Run it in Chrome if you can. http://codepen.io/shuffguy/pen/JdLXeM

This was a quick example, but if you play around with the keyframe resizing properties you can definitely emulate that example exactly with keyframes.

Comment: If you also include `transform: scaleY(xx)` in the animation you can make it appeared stretched.

Answer (score 2):

U can use the @keyframe animation in css for this, just take a look: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

And here is a exemple what i made with keyframes and jquery animate:

Css

```
#box{
            display: block;
            background: red;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        @keyframes change_form {
          0% {
            width: 300px;
          }
          50% {
            border-radius: 0%;
            width: 50px;
            height: 100px;
          }
          100% {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
          }
        }
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   window.setTimeout(function(){
    $( "#box" ).animate({ 
                        "top":"+=134px"
                        ,
                    },{
    step: function(now) {
                if (now >= 11) {
                    $("#box").css({'transition':'all linear 1s', 'animation':'change_form ease 2s '});
                }
            } }
        );
    }, 2000);
});
```

In a simple Div

```
   <div id="box"></div>
```

Just a example what i make to show u how to make this effect, u can make this only with css, just putting the 'animation' in your div